# Interfacing with Html And Android

Tags: android, html, adobe, media-player

I have developed a media player in `Html`.Now my job is to play `streaming Url` in `Html` coded media player coming from `Android` activity.So i have need to pass url from `android activity` to `Html` media player files where it will be play.I have searched lot but haven't find any good solution.please suggest me. Thanks

**Java Code**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
//      String LocalFile = "file:///android_asset/android.html";

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String html = "<embed src=\"file:///android_asset/"
                + "android.html"
                + " \"play=\"true\" loop=\"true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"> <embed>";
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html,
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        String str = "rtmp://23.21.155.146:554/9016012507701502509011502505116016019xm150.sdp";
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:passWebUrl('" + str + "')");
```

**My Code for media player**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            height:100%;
        }
        #altContent{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <title>YOUR TITLE HERE!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
    function passWebUrl(url)
 {
        alert(url);
 }
        flashvars.HaloColor = "0x0086db";
        flashvars.ToolTips = "true";
        flashvars.AutoPlay = "true";
        flashvars.VolumeLevel = "50";
        flashvars.CaptionURL = "YOUR CAPTION HERE";
        flashvars.Title = "YOUR TITLE HERE";
        flashvars.Logo = "";
        flashvars.SRC = "Here is my url link should comes from Android Activity";
        flashvars.BufferTime = "5";
        flashvars.AutoHideControls = "false";
        flashvars.IsLive = "true";

        var params = {};
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";

        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "L3MP";

        swfobject.embedSWF("http://media-player.cdn.level3.net/flash/v1_1_1/Level3MediaPlayer.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.1.0","http://media-player.cdn.level3.net/flash/v1_1_1/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="altContent">
       <center> <BR><BR><span style="color:red"><b>Please Install Adobe Flash Player</b>  
            </span><BR><BR>
      <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img     src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a>
      </center>    
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: reason for Downvote give reasone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing the value of variable from your java class to the javascript function in your html page you have to use this code. Try this:

```
String str = "variable_value";
webView.loadUrl("javascript:functionName('"+ str +"')");
```

**EDIT : -**

```
 function passWebUrl(url)
 {
        alert(url);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Chirag but u tell me how can i get this value in Html

Comment: @Dipu you have to make one javascript function in html page with string parameter . you get passed str in that javascript function.

Comment: My html file is inside assets folder then how can i call that javascript method from java.please make me clear

Comment: @Dipu create above function in your html and pass through activity as i suggest .

Comment: @Dipu i didn't find passWebUrl function in your media player html file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16683/discussion-between-chirag-raval-and-dipu)